# Can PyCharm be configured to find custom module imports?

Tags: pycharm

I have a custom module spark_utils with a class `SparkUtils` that is included in the current `pycharm` project under a folder marked as `Sources`.

[image]

However `Pycharm` is not finding it for imports and so I'll have to go enter the full path manually:

[image]

[image]

I added the parent `autostats` and the import now works:

[image]

It is surprising that `Pycharm` could not help me out more here. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Related: *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)*

Comment: @PeterMortensen This question is not centered on the specifics of the code but rather the behavior of the IDE.  I nearly always post code otherwise.

Comment: Can you try marking autostats directory as *Source Root*? Currently, you mark framework directory as source root but spark_utils.py is in autostats.

Comment: @Thy  `autostats` is part of the module path / package name so it would not be correct.

Comment: Marking framework directory as Source Root is the reason why you can do `from autostats.spark_utils ..` but not `from spark_utils ..` in PyCharm. Once you mark autostats as source root, PyCharm should be able to find `spark_utils`.

Comment: Please re-read and review the very last sections/screenshots: I am specifically mentioning that it is necessary for me to manually enter `autostats.spark_utils` The question is "why can't pycharm help me find them?"